# rds sql query time out on aplication joins

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7

I'm using MyISAM table.

On the local server we didn't have any queries problems but when I moved to amazon rds we started having problems with long queries and big inner joins in the client application.

Configs:
max_execution_time = 0; (i try to set on maximum but have any changes).

Before on the local server it took a long time but brought the results to amazon I get a time out error image below..

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you know that you can `Ctrl+C` the `Message Box`es?

Comment: Yes, i know... but the print screen is easy.

Comment: Are you getting this message when trying to connect to RDS server?

Comment: You could start by checking the database logs on aws on: 
RDS -> Databases -> your-database -> tab: Logs & events

Comment: @MouhamadOnayssi Im getting this message when execute a query with multiple join table, I dont have problem to connect..

Comment: @FellipeSanches "(Got timeout reading communication packets)"

Comment: @Lucas have you seen this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205398/mysql-got-timeout-reading-communication-packets-when-reading-federated-table